# Sorting block of lines matching only the first one

Tags: sort, text-formatting, nmap

I have an Nmap output file like this:

```
Nmap scan report for AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.akamaitechnologies.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set (0.027s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:24 CEST for 15s
PORT    STATE SERVICE  REASON         VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http syn-ack ttl 59 AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration/Mirror service)
Nmap scan report for AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.akamaitechnologies.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set.
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 2s
PORT     STATE    SERVICE      REASON      VERSION
2222/tcp filtered EtherNetIP-1 no-response
Nmap scan report for CCCCCCCCCCC. googleusercontent.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set (0.15s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 3s
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON         VERSION
2222/tcp open  ssh     syn-ack ttl 55 ProFTPD mod_sftp 0.9.9 (protocol 2.0)
Nmap scan report for BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Host is up, received user-set (0.16s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 3s
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON         VERSION
2222/tcp open  ssh     syn-ack ttl 51 ProFTPD mod_sftp 0.9.9 (protocol 2.0)
Nmap scan report for AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.akamaitechnologies.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set (0.027s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:24 CEST for 15s
PORT    STATE SERVICE  REASON         VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http syn-ack ttl 59 AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration/Mirror service)
```

I would like to sort this file for every 5 line block using as sorting match "Nmap scan report for ", the output should be :

```
Nmap scan report for AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.akamaitechnologies.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set (0.027s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:24 CEST for 15s
PORT    STATE SERVICE  REASON         VERSION
443/tcp open  ssl/http syn-ack ttl 59 AkamaiGHost (Akamai's HTTP Acceleration/Mirror service)
Nmap scan report for AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA.akamaitechnologies.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set.
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 2s
PORT     STATE    SERVICE      REASON      VERSION
2222/tcp filtered EtherNetIP-1 no-response
Nmap scan report for BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Host is up, received user-set (0.16s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 3s
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON         VERSION
2222/tcp open  ssh     syn-ack ttl 51 ProFTPD mod_sftp 0.9.9 (protocol 2.0)
Nmap scan report for CCCCCCCCCCC. googleusercontent.com (IP)
Host is up, received user-set (0.15s latency).
Scanned at 2016-10-09 14:43:21 CEST for 3s
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON         VERSION
2222/tcp open  ssh     syn-ack ttl 55 ProFTPD mod_sftp 0.9.9 (protocol 2.0)
```

a solution using unix commands is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For each block of five lines concatenate lines (e.g. use a low ascii char like `\x02` which is unlikely to occur in your input - assuming your tools support it), sort on 1st field then restore the newlines:

```
sed 'N;N;N;N;s/\n/\x02/g' infile | sort -t$'\02' -k1,1 | tr '\02' '\n'
```